# Layout mess-up when JavaScript "keyup" run in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-events

I create simple function when `keyup` using JavaScript like so :

```
<script>
//when press enter, submit this form, when press shift and enter create new line
$("#text_reply1778").keyup(function(e) {
    var textVal = $(this).val();
    if(e.which == 13 && e.shiftKey) {
        //here create new line
    }
    else if (e.which == 13) {
       e.preventDefault(); 
       var text_input = $("#text_reply1778").val();
       
       if(text_input != '') { //dont submit if value is empty
       
           $('#reply1778').ajaxSubmit( {
                target: '#reply_output1778', 
                success: function() { 
                    //do somthing here
                } 
            });  
       }
    }
});
</script>
```

When I run this using browser Google Chrome *Version 26.0.1410.43* my layout will mess-up but this not happen when I'm using Firefox.

You can try from here (full code) [chat1.html](http://www.bsx-multihack.org/chat1.html) , then type any message inside textarea(*chat box*) then you will see layout will mess-up.

So how to avoid this? Any method that I can use? I tried to replace `keyup` with `keypress` but the result was still the same.

Comment: I moved your `index_reload` container just under the opening body tag and it seems to be behaving okay after the change in Chrome. Can you give this a go and tell me if it makes any difference?

Comment: @Stefan V   its working.. thanks.. but i notice when i change this container ID <div id="container"> to another name it start working.. weird ..

Comment: I believe it comes from your `overflow:hidden` CSS value. See if you can continue without it:)

Comment: @Stefan V  yaa.. when i remove 
    overflow:hidden it start working without any issue..